# Play framework 2.3.2: How to render List or Map in scala template

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I am trying to display a list of strings as a repeatable input text control in my view. Here is my model:

```
public class User {
    @Required
    public String email;
    public String password;
    public List<String> products;
}
```

Controller:

```
    public static Result index() {
    Form<User> userForm = Form.form(User.class);

    Map<String,String> anyData = new HashMap<String,String>();
    List<String> listProduct = new ArrayList<String>();
    listProduct.add("p1");
    listProduct.add("p2");
    userForm = userForm.fill(new User("bob@gmail.com", "secret", listProduct));
    return ok(views.html.index.render(userForm));
}
```

View:

```
@(userForm: Form[models.User])
@import helper._
@import models.User
@import scala._

@main("Welcome to Play") {

<form id="formUser" action="/user/apply" method="post">
    @inputText(userForm("email"))
    @inputText(userForm("password"))
    @for(product <- userForm("products")) {
      <input type="text" name="@product" value="@product">
    }

    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
}
```

Error is:

```
value map is not a member of play.data.Form.Field
```

I also tried form helper @repeat. But its just not working.

```
    @repeat(userForm("products"), min = 0) { 
        product => @inputText(product)
    }
```

Error:

```
not found: value product
```

I am using Play 2.3.2 in Java. 
Any idea whats going wrong?

Suraj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remember that view templates are parsed to Scala functions and code is escaped with **@** character. Your second solution works fine. In this case you just need to format your code in proper way and it works like a charm.

```
@repeat(userForm("products"), min = 0) { product => 
  @inputText(product)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I formatted code and as you sad, it works like charm. I also took a note of your comment about escaping character and understood the issue.

Comment: @Suraj i don't understand the issue about the escaping character - can someone enlighten me? Also, is it possible to use at-for, or can this only be done with at-repeat?